# Turning Cortana back on

Tags: cortana

I turned Cortana off by mistake and would like to turn it back on but it is asking for old password to confirm but I do not remember the old password.  How can I turn this on again please?

Comment: You can visit the https://account.microsoft.com and try to restore your password.

Comment: Which password is it asking for?

Comment: I have switched off Cortana and turned in back on. It didn't ask for a password. Can you elaborate what password it is asking?